# Using Cairo, how can I open up a window and draw lines by using inputs from a console?

Tags: visual-c++, cairo

I'm trying to make an application where when a user inputs a direction, it moves a point towards that direction (basically creates a path like say right,right,right makes it draw a line ---), but how do I open the image in real time as Cairo always saves the image? I want the person to be able to input it from the console. I am new to Cairo and its functions and I only have experience with consoles only.

I haven't seen a way to open it in a new window, it only saves in a png file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cairo does rendering. It does not do things like interacting with a windowing system. For that, you can use Gtk+. Gtk+ does use cairo for its rendering.